# Как получить Transform двухмерного объекта по нажатию

Tags: unity3d

Есть мир с некоторым количеством игровых объектов. Каждый игровой объект имеет трехмерный меш, но двухмерное твердое тело, и двухмерный PolygonCollider, который НЕ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ ТРИГГЕРОМ. Игрок управляет ортографической камерой, расположенной на высоте 10 единиц. Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на игровой объект камера начинала за ним следовать. И все бы ничего но я не могу получить объект при нажатии, так как функция OnMouseDown() не работает с коллайдерами, не являющимися триггерами, а RayCast с камеры просто проходит сквозь двухмерный коллайдер, не задевая его. Как мне обойти эту проблему?

Comment: `Physics2D.Raycast()` не должен "промахиваться" по своим коллайдерам. Возможно, вы что-то не так используете. Если у вас персонажи все таки по глубине расположены - используйте объемный коллайдер и рейкаст и не парьтесь

Comment: Я надеялся, что есть более элегантное решение, потому что объемный коллайдер при двумерной физике выглядит излишним

Comment: Я где-то слышал, что трехмерная физика (в т.ч. рейкаст) не будет взаимодействовать с двухмерной. Но не уверен.

Comment: В этом и проблема

Comment: @Observer189, у вас на камере висит 2dRaycaster и он не попадает в 2d физ.объекты?